# Jacobian of smooth function on smooth foliations is smooth (or Holder)?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems

If I have a smooth function $f\in C^\infty(M)$ where $M$ is compact, and a smooth integrable distribution $E$ of $M$ (so a smooth assignment of vector spaces to $TM$). For simplicity, assume $E$ is one dimensional, is $|df|_E|$ smooth (or at least Holder) on M with respects to the Riemannian metric?

It will be very helpful if someone can give some me some counter-examples to work on.

----Edits----

It is pointed out in the comment that it is not clear what a smooth distribution means. There are two definitions of the regularity of distribution that will be helpful to me.

(1) The regularity of the plane fields corresponding to the distribution, defined similarly to vector fields. Take local coordinates and define regularity of plane fields in charts. For vector $v\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $k$-dimensional subspaces $E, A, B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, define
$$d(v,E) =  \min_{w\in E} d(v,w)$$
which is the length to the projection. Then define
$$d(A,B)=\max \left\{ \max_{v\in A, \|v\|=1} d(v,B), \max_{w\in B, \|w\|=1} d(w,A) \right\}. $$
I am requiring this regularity measured with respects to the distance in plane fields and the Riemannian metric of $M$ to be Holder or smooth.

(1.5) I think the following definition is equivalent to (1): for $r\in \mathbb{R}_+$, $C^r$ regularity of plane fields means $C^r$ sections of the Grassmanian bundle $G^k M$.

(2) Mostly helpful to my contexts are the $C^r$vector fields tangent to $C^r$ foliations of $M$. A foliation is a division of $M$ into leaves $\mathscr{F}_p$, injectively immersed $k$-dimensional submanifolds, for points $p\in M$. They are given by foliation boxes $\phi: D^k\times D^{n-k}\to U$ such that $\phi(D^k\times y)\subset \mathscr{F}_q$, where $U\subset M$ is a neighborhood of $q=\phi(0,y)$ and $y\in D^{n-k}$. Require $C^r$ foliations to have $C^r$ foliation boxes.

Comment: Isn’t the restriction of a smooth bundle map to a subbundle — integrable or not — always smooth?

Comment: @TedShifrin I know that $df:TM\to TM$ is smooth on $TM$, so in particular smooth on $TM|_E$, but is it clear that the function is smooth with respects to the Riemannian metric of $M$ too? For example, if the distribution isn't Holder (or continuous), then I could probably see the statement not being true.

Comment: What does a Riemannian metric have to do with it? You said the distribution was smooth; I guess you did not mean it.

Comment: You need to include way more detail if you’re going to use standard language in a non-standard way. We are not all coming at this from your specialized perspective.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for the advice. I have now updated the definitions.